# Block or warn about entries which are mostly uppercase

Tags: feature-request

I'm suggesting to block or to display a warning if an answer or question is mostly consisting of uppercase characters.

Something along the lines of "It seems like your Shift-Key is stuck, you might wanna correct your post".

Comment: What about languages that use uppercase keywords?

Comment: @BoltClock: Good point...maybe leaving code-parts out of the loop?

Comment: What about COBOL, where everything is bloody uppercase?  I think leaving out comment blocks, pre blocks, and quote blocks would be necessary.  But at that point why bother?

Comment: I would limit it on the title only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this actually to try and help people with a stuck <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, or just a snarky way of telling people they shouldn't type all in caps? I think the former will probably notice without our help and the latter won't care

Answer (score 0):

Site: superuser.com
Question title: *"HELP; MY TEXT IS ALL CAPS! HOW TO TURN THIS OFF?"*

Site: stackoverflow.com
Question title: Handling REALLY_LONG_UPPER_CASE_EVENT_NAME

Comment: HELP MY MOUSE IS MOVING BY IT SELF

Comment: @Michael: Hm, have you tried fixating it with duct tape?

Comment: Related: ["HELP MY CAPS LOCK IS STUCK!!!!? " on Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100905105656AAQ10rv)